# Django form post(AJAX) direct to somewhere else

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms

i know my question is quite vague and also has been asked so many times(but i can't understand any of the solutions).what i want to go is to url `search_res/save_tweet` and pass data from template `show_tweets.html` in json format using AJAX.

i think my ajax is not working. and when i press button it goes to somewhere `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search_res/?`

I am new to both django and ajax.

show_tweets.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tweets Result</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        save_tweets = function(tweet_id,created_at,text,lang){
            alert(tweet_id,created_at,text,lang);
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : '/search_res/save_tweet/',
                dataType : 'json',
                data: {
                    'tweet_id' : tweet_id,
                    'created_at' : created_at,
                    'text' : text,
                    'lang' : lang
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Tweets Results</h1>
<ul>
    {% for k,v in json_d %}
        <div>
            {{ k }} : {{ v.full_text }}
            <form onsubmit="save_tweets('{{ v.id_str }} , {{ v.created_at }} , {{ v.full_text }} , {{ v.lang }}')">{% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit" value="Toxic"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
def show_tweets(request):
if request.GET['hashtag'] and request.GET['user']:
    template = loader.get_template('error.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render({},request))
else:
    if request.GET['hashtag']:
        hashtag= request.GET['hashtag']
        try: all_tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=hashtag + ' -filter:retweets', tweet_mode='extended').items(100)
        except: print("error")
        d = {}
        cnt = 0
        for t in all_tweets:
            cnt += 1
            d['Tweet_' + str(cnt)] = t._json
        dump_d = json.dumps(d)
        json_d = json.loads(dump_d)
    else:
        user = request.GET['user']
        try: all_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=user, count=100, include_rts=True, tweet_mode='extended')
        except: print("error")
        d = {}
        cnt = 0
        for t in all_tweets:
            cnt += 1
            d['Tweet_' + str(cnt)] = t._json
        dump_d = json.dumps(d)
        json_d = json.loads(dump_d)
    context = {'json_d': json_d.items()}
    return render(request,'show_tweets.html',context)

def save_tweet(request):
    data = request.POST.get('tweet_id')
    print(data);
    #tweets(Text = data).save()
    return render(request,'success.html')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^search_res/$', views.show_tweets,name='show_tweets'),
    url(r'^search_res/save_tweet/$', views.save_tweet,name='save_tweet')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i noticed was in your **views.py** in the save_tweet function you are using :

```
 data = request.GET.get('tweet_id')
```

However since you are posting your data you should use

```
 data = request.POST.get('tweet_id')
```

EDIT: 
After reading your comment clarifying what you want, it looks like you are using AJAX when you would rather be using the standard form action.So your code would looks something like:

```
<form action="/search_res/save_tweet/" method="post" id="form">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ v.id_str }}"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ v.created_at }}"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ v.full_text }}"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ v.lang }}"/>
 </form>
```

Or you could have your save_tweet function in your views.py file return a success message and handle the success in the Ajax success function:

**views.py**

```
def save_tweet(request):
    data = request.POST.get('tweet_id')
    print(data);
    #tweets(Text = data).save()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"data":data}), status=200,content_type="application/json")
```

**show_tweets.html**

```
 $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/search_res/save_tweet/',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: {
                'tweet_id' : tweet_id,
                'created_at' : created_at,
                'text' : text,
                'lang' : lang
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus,jqXHR) {
                if(jqXHR.status === 200) {
                    window.location.replace('success.html')
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: it doesn't matter much.. i want the page to redirect me to `127.0.0.1:8000/search_res/save_tweets` instead of  `127.0.0.1:8000/search_res/?`